# How can you getKeyByAltName in Pymongo using Field Level Encryption?

Tags: mongodb, encryption, pymongo, client-side

I have been trying to get the keys I have generated with this repo https://github.com/mongodb-developer/python-quickstart-code and it is really useful for creating keys in python, however how do you get a key for an altname?

I thought perhaps it is best to try running commands like: `db.command("getKeyByAltName", keyAltName="nameofkeyaltnameadmin")` but I get the error getKeyByAltName does not exist:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'getKeyByAltName', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "no such command: 'getKeyByAltName'", 'code': 59, 'codeName': 'CommandNotFound'}
```

even though it definitely does according to the docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/KeyVault.getKeyByAltName/ can anyone help me with this? I am a bit stuck...

My mongodb version is:

```
db version v6.0.3
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "f803681c3ae19817d31958965850193de067c516",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getKeyByAltName` is a method of a KeyVault object. It is a client-side field level encryption method.

[db.command](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command) is for running [database commands](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/#database-commands) on the server.

Comment: Yup, found the function     def get_key_by_alt_name(self, key_alt_name: str) in the client encryption class

Answer (score 0):

This method should be in a ClientEncryption object (see for example a test [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/bcb0ac0170a712391b353531d865f6cb43d83bc1/test/test_on_demand_csfle.py#L48)), I'm not a python developer, but getKeyByAltName  should be there

Comment: Ah yes you are right, somehow I missed that function